# Javascript and Inheritance

Tags: javascript

Say I have a *Class*:

```
function Foo() {
  this.foo1 =  null;
  this.foo2 = function() { return false;};
}
```

And I want other objects to inherit variables & functions from it.

```
function Bar(){}
function Baz(){}
```

Then instantiate my objects:

```
var bar = new Bar();
bar.foo1   // returns null
bar.foo2() // returns false
```

What's the proper function to *include* `Foo` in `Bar` and `Baz`?

---

I already did `Bar.prototype = new Foo();` but it seems to fail on our beloved IE (<9).

Comment: This is definitely not a unique question. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attach all the properties to the prototype (which is preferable, at least for methods),

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.foo1 = null;
Foo.prototype.foo2 = function() { return false;};
```

then assigning the parent's prototype to the child's prototype is sufficient:

```
function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    var Tmp = function(){};
    Tmp.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new Tmp();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

inherit(Bar, Foo);
```

Here we used an intermediate constructor function to "decouple" the two prototypes. Otherwise if you'd change one, you'd change the other one too (as they reference the same object). This way is actually pretty popular and used by a couple of libraries.

If not, you have to call the parent's constructor function inside the child's constructor function:

```
function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this);
}
```

This is something you always should do, to assign the properties set up in the constructor function to the current object.

---

An additional remark to your way:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

this *should* work (also in IE actually), but it has two major flaws:

- All the *instance properties* set up in `Foo` will become properties shared by all `Bar` instances.
- What if `Foo` expects some arguments that are only available when you create a `Bar` instance?

Answer (score 1):

have a look to [Classy](http://classy.pocoo.org/) or, if you like Ruby and want a more complete solution to [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/). Those libraries helps you with object orientation in javascript ad hide prototype to the developer.

Hope this helps