# Javascript inheritance and privileged functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is it possible to inherit *privileged* methods in Javascript?  In the below, Widget successfully inherits the `D` function, but not `subscribe`.  Changing the second line in inherit to `f.prototype = new base();` seems to work, but I know that's bad for all sorts of reasons.  Is there a clean way to do this, or do I have to make everything public?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302448/javascript-and-inheritance/7302500#7302500) seems to imply that I have to make the methods public (attach to prototype) but I'd like to ask directly.

```
    function EventRaiser() {
        var events = {};
        this.subscribe = function(key, func) { /* elided */ };
    }
    EventRaiser.prototype.D = function() { alert("D"); };

    function Widget() { }

    function Inherit(sub, base) {
        function f() { }
        f.prototype = base.prototype;
        sub.prototype = new f();
        sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
    }

    Inherit(Widget, EventRaiser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.subscribe = function(key, func) { /* elided */ };`

here your adding a method to the current `thisContext`.

`Inherit(Widget, EventRaiser)`

Here your saling the prototype Widget should consume the prototype EventRaiser.

The best you can do is to not mix `this.x` with `prototype.y`

Or you can call `EventRaiser.call(this)` inside `function Widget() { }` but that's bad style.

If your going to use an inheritance pattern I would recommend you use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) & [`pd`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd) :

```
// prototype
var EventRaiser = {
    D: function() { alert("D"); },
    subscribe: function(key, func) { ... }
};
// factory
var eventRaiser = function _eventRaiser(proto) {
    proto = proto || EventRaiser;
    return Object.create(proto, pd({
        events: {}
    }));  
};

// prototype
var Widget = {
    ...    
};
// factory
var widget = function _widget() {
    var o = eventRaiser(pd.merge(Widget, EventRaiser));
    Object.defineProperties(o, pd({
        ... 
    });
    return o;
};
```

Or if you insist `Widget` should inherit from `EventRaiser`

```
var Widget = Object.create(EventRaiser, pd({
    ...
});
var widget = function _widget() {
    var o = eventRaiser(Widget);
    Object.defineProperties(o, pd({
        ...
    });
    return o;
}
```

The reasons for recommending this pattern is a clear seperation of the prototype and the factory. This allows you to interact with the prototype without handling the factory. With the use of the `new` keyword you muddy those waters (as shown in your code) and you also tend to hack `this` around.

The above code also doesn't look elegant. This means that your realy aught to look for a different pattern. For example `EventEmitter` from node.js has an [explicit check](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L104) for the `this._events` object which makes the factory code more elegant.

Comment: `EventRaiser.call(this)` is what I thought I needed.  Why is that bad style?  Chaining to your base ctor is common practice in OO Languages, and even this JS sample does it  http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: @AdamRackis There is no notion of base constructor. Your emulating classical OO and Java in JavaScript. That's bad style

Answer (score 1):

Your privileged method `this.subscribe` is only ever attached to an *instance* of `EventRaiser`.

This should be obvious when you consider that this line:

```
this.subscribe = function(...) { } ;
```

is only ever executed when `EventRaiser()` is called.

If you don't create an `EventRaiser` object that property is simply never there to be inherited from.